# Same distribution and median on all five features in point cloud dataset, weird?

Tags: machine-learning

I wanna start off by saying I'm new to asking questions on forums, so I'll try to do it as best as I can...

**Backstory:**
I'm using point cloud data from an FMCW radar to do binary classification for human activity recognition. When I evaluate the model on the test data (unseen data) it gets an accuracy of 81%. However, during live tests when deployed it performs poorly and sometimes feels like flipping a coin.

I plotted histograms to take a better look at the data that I collected. I know I should've plotted histograms earlier when visualizing the data but simply forgot to do it.

**Good to know:**
The features are Elevation, Azimuth, Doppler, Range, and SNR. The data is recorded from two radars, positioned in the corner of a room and the other placed in the opposite corner. The plots show the histogram for each feature across the whole dataset.

**The problem:**

I'm starting to get worried that something weird is going on with the data since the histograms for the features are identical and the median is practically the same. I'd expect some kind of offset in the median since not all features have the same unit (Range has meters, SNR has steps of 0.1 dB and Azimuth has radians). There is interference between the radars of course, but should only cause problems with some values (which often result in outliers).

There is a total of 62,046,400 numerical values per feature.

- Elevation median: 0.791562
- Azimuth median: 0.795468
- Doppler median: 0.796543
- Range median: 0.797557
- SNR median: 0.797557

**Histograms:**

Y-axis is amount, X-axis is the numerical value

### **Azimuth**

[image: Azimuth]

### **Doppler**

[image: Doppler]

### **Elevation**

[image: Elevation]

### **Range**

[image: Range]

### **SNR**

[image: SNR]

Comment: Could you provide a direct link to the data or a subset of the data exhibiting these qualities? Like you, I suspect you're reading the same data multiple times, not different bands of data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @barrycarter. After further debugging, I found out that the data I was retrieving from the radar was actually just garbage data, mostly random values. I recorded new data after making sure that the data I was retrieving was actually right. Now none of the histograms are identical and I get a classification accuracy of 95% on the test set. The model also performs very well on tests when deployed. 


TLDR: I was parsing the wrong data from the radar, resulting in random values.